# Send data to backend submit() is not a function

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to send to the backend the value of this multiple choice question but I don't understand why I get the error of the type

```
document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function
```

I double checked that nothing else has been named "submit" (many people had this error)

I tried doing like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_submit), but I get:

```
createlist:19 Uncaught TypeError: data.submit is not a function
    at sendGenre (createlist:19)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (createlist:59)
```

My code is:

```js
function sendGenre() {
  data = document.getElementById("genre").value;
  console.log(data);
  data.submit();
}
```

```html
<div class="bioContainer">
  <form class="adminPlaylistMainForm" id="genreForm" method="POST">
    <div class="adminPlaylistGenre">
      <p>From what genre do you want to select the music ?</p>
      <select class="adminPlaylistGenreButton" id="genre">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
        <option value="punk">Punk</option>
        <option value="rock">Rock</option>
      </select>
      <p><input type="button" onclick="sendGenre();" value="Submit form" /></p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea of what's causing the problem ?

Comment: Replace genre by genreForm.
You are trying to call submit from a select element instead of a form.

Comment: I think you should also have an `action=""` attribute in your form element to submit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're grabbing `select` element instead of `form`.

Change your JS code inside script to the following:-

```
<script>
  function sendGenre() {
    let data = document.getElementById("genre").value;
    let form = document.getElementById("genreForm")
    console.log(data);
   form.submit();
  }
</script>
```